# Changing mouse polling rate

Tags: kubuntu, mouse

I am in need of reducing my mouse polling rate. When running

```
cat /sys/module/usbhid/parameters/mousepoll
```

it will return a value of 0, which is very high.

I have tried the classic recommended fix, which is to run

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

but konsole returns

```
sudo: gedit: command not found
```

which... doesn't get me anywhere

Any help what to do with this?

Running Kubuntu 14.04, kernel version 3.13.0-53-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gedit is GNOME's editor. It doesn't come installed by default on Kubuntu. You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Or use another editor already installed, like kate:

```
sudo kate /etc/modules
```

Comment: Thanks. However, now a new problem. I changed the settings with 
-r usbhid
usbhid mousepoll=8

yet, when I do cat, it still returns 0

Comment: With that I can't help you, I'm afraid. Maybe you should make a another question or unaccept this one.