# How to change mouse polling rate?

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, touchpad

I have tried these two:
[Changing mouse polling rate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629520/changing-mouse-polling-rate?newreg=ba8a70c2d4ba46848357432077f4a6c7)

https://www.urbanterror.info/forums/topic/21844-howto-changing-mouse-polling-rate-on-ubuntu/

First of all, I use Windows 11 and Kubuntu 21.10. I have two different bluetooth mouse I get coil whine when using one and not while using the other one (I get coil whine when touching the touchpad as well) but only on linux. So I thought maybe the problem is the polling rate (just a random thought if you have a better idea pls lmk). I tried to follow the above links but my polling rate still remained 0. So how may I go about changing the polling rate.

Comment: Welcome to AU. Have you tried the troublesome mouse on a different computer? Might just be failing hardware?

Comment: I use my laptop as dualboot with windows 11 and I don’t get coil whine on windows. I used to get the exact same issue on ubuntu 20.04 and 21.10 as well. So as a last resort thought about changing the polling rate.

Comment: do update your question with the information that it's dual boot and doesn't happen with windows - I can't help but it might help someone help you.